# Recursive code in Python

Tags: python, recursion

I got this python code that returns True or False if a given list of numbers has a subset value that adds to tar, but i want to generate it without the for loop.
Any ideas on how i can make it without the loop, but only with the recursion?

```
def sub_sum(num, tar):

    if tar == 0:
        return True

    b=len(num)

    for a in range(b):
        if sub_sum(num[a+1:] + num[:a], tar - num[a]):
            return True
    return False
```

For example:

```
>>>sub_sum([6,7,8], 13)
True
>>>sub_sum([6,7,8], 50)
False
```

Comment: you could do it with a `any([list comprehension])` method but that just moves the loop into the list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

Iteration can always be replaced by recursion, however there is typically no good reason to do so, and engineers usually try to go in the opposite direction (first write out a recursive solution, then convert it to an iterable one).

For purely academic purposes, here is an example of a naive replacement of iteration by recursion:

```
for a in [4,3,2,1,0]: 
    print(a)

print()

def fun(start = 4):
    if start >= 0:
        print(start)
        fun(start-1)

fun()
```

Output:

4
3
2
1
0

4
3
2
1
0

... And of course you could replace your loop with this silly code.